# Propel one save call instead of one for each row

Tags: symfony, propel

is there a way to issue one INSERT statement instead of calling save() method on each object? Can I call save() on PropelObjectCollection?

Is there a way so I can call one save statement and save a whole set of rows instead of calling save per row?

To illustrate, I currently have this code:

```
    while($node = $streamer->getNode())
    {
        $profile = simplexml_load_string($node);

        $profileHandler = new Profile();
        $profileHandler->setBlob($profileXml);
        $profileHandler->setUserId($userId);
        $profileHandler->setHome($profile->home);
        $profileHandler->setJob($profile->job);
        $profileHandler->setTown($profile->town);
        $profileHandler->setUpdatedat($profile['updated']);
        $profileHandler->save();
    }
```

Can I call one save method at the end of my while loop? Or is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to call `Save()` once, using the `PropelObjectCollection`, try this:

```
$tempArray = [];
while($node = $streamer->getNode())
{
    $profile = simplexml_load_string($node);

    $tempArray[] = [
        'Blob'      => $profileXml,
        'UserId'    => $userId,
        'Home'      => $profile->home,
        'Job'       => $profile->job,
        'Town'      => $profile->town,
        'Updatedat' => $profile['updated']
    ];
}

$oCollection = new PropelObjectCollection();
$oCollection->setModel('Profile');
$oCollection->fromArray($tempArray);
$oCollection->save();
```